# PHP get data from other page using public static function

Tags: php, html

(sorry for my bad English)

I'm creating a website where users can post something and other users can leave a comment on that post.

I learned from a video from HowCode (youtube) that if you want to display the comments on multiple pages, it is usefull to create 1 page that selects the comments and on all the other pages I can 'include' those comments.

**The problem is that it now only displays one comment** while I have multiple comments on some posts.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

On the page where I select the comments:

```
class Comment {
          public static function displayComments($postId) {

                  $comments = DB::query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = $postId');

                  foreach($comments as $comment) {
                  $commentDisplay = $comment['comment'].' ~ by a user';

                  return $commentDisplay;
                  }
          }
}
```

On the page where I display the comments:

```
$showComments = Comment::displayComments($_GET['postid']);
echo $showComments;
```

Comment: Your code might be vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a single comment, you should push all comments related to the post in an array and return it.

```
class Comment {
    public static function displayComments($postId) {
        $comments = DB::query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = $postId');
        $commentDisplay = array();
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            $commentDisplay[] = $comment['comment'].' ~ by a user';
        }
        return $commentDisplay;
    }
}
```

And then loop through the returned array to display all comments.

```
$showComments = Comment::displayComments($_GET['postid']);
foreach($showComments as $comment){
    // display comment 
    // echo $comment . '<br />';
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, it works now but I want to display the comments inside an `echo`. I tried inside the foreach `$commentDisplay = $comment;` and then (outside the foreach) `echo 'blah'.$commentDisplay.'blahblah';` but that gave me one comment. Do I have to make the echo inside the foreach so I can use `$comment` to display each comment, or can set a variable inside the foreach?

Comment: @HansDeVis, `$commentDisplay` is an array now, you cannot `echo` it to display comments. As stated above, you have to loop through the array to display all comments. Paste your current code snippet(s) in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is happening because you are returning on the first iteration of the foreach.

When you `return` it immediately exists the method `displayComments()` and therefore only displays the first one.

What you want to do is return all the comments by adding them to an array and turning the array:

```
class Comment {
    public static function displayComments($postId) {
        $comments = DB::query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = $postId');
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            $commentDisplay[] = $comment['comment'].' ~ by a user';
        }
        return commentDisplay;
    }
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
$showComments = Comment::displayComments($_GET['postid']); // this is an array
echo array_values($showComments);
```

Or use `foreach` on `$showComments` if you want to print it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dependency  injection...you should as below more flex more elastic,also data mapping support to user class

```
class Comment {
         public  function displayComments($postId) {

             $data = DB::query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = $postId')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

              return  $data;



          }


}



class User
{

    private $comment;

     private $name;

     private $id;
   function __construct(Comment $comment,int $postid)
   {

       $this->comment=$comment;

         $this->id=$postid;
    }

  function comment()
  {
        return $this->comment->displayComments($this->id)['comment'];

   function name()
   {

    $this->comment->displayComments($this->id)['name'];

     }


 }


$comment=new Comment ();

$user=new User($comment,$postid);

echo $user->comment() .':'.$user->name();
```